# Are events only useful for real-time listening by dapps?

Tags: dapps, events

Why would I need to use events when I can access a contract's variables through the automatic accessor functions?

Please explain the use of and/or need for events.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-events-over-dedicated-indexed-variable

Answer (score 2):

**No**, not exclusively for real-time updates.

Events are inexpensive, well-organized storage, so there are many possible uses.

Have a look here, for example. [How can we retrieve the evolution of the state of an smart contract variable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11119/how-can-we-retrieve-the-evolution-of-the-state-of-an-smart-contract-variable/11121#11121)

*In my opinion* it's a good habit to emit events that describe all state changes in the contract.

Hope it helps.